# How do I filter out list starting with a specific first letter (laravel/eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I have a list of strings and only want to get the strings starting with the letter 'B'. I have tried the following code without success.

```
{{ $kentekens->where('kenteken', 'LIKE', 'B%') }}
```

and

```
{{ $kentekens->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return strpos($value, 'B') === 0;
    });
}}
```

### Controller

```
public function create() {
        $kentekens = Kenteken::latest()
            ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
            ->get();

return view('layouts.dashboard', compact('kentekens'));
```

Anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: show the result of `$kentekens`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get only data that starts from B, do this:

```
Kenteken::latest()
    ->where('kenteken', 'like', 'B%')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
    ->get();
```

Comment: ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())
Having this as a second 'where' doesn't seem to be working. If I use it without the first 'where' then it works.. otherwise not

Answer (score 2):

You can try use the function helper `starts_with` to check with a value starts with `B`. Something like this:

```
$kentekens = $kentekens->filter(function ($value, $key) {
   return starts_with($value, 'B');
})
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-starts-with

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `get()`.

Just replace:

`$kentekens->where('kenteken', 'LIKE', 'B%')`

by:

`$kentekens->where('kenteken', 'LIKE', 'B%')->get()`